Is it possible to trigger voice recognition on voice activation?
So I have a voice recognition app in Unity using Microsoft Azure that calls the voice recognition on button click. As far as I can tell you need something to trigger the voice recognition, either a button click/key press for RecognizeOnceAsync(), or in the case of StartContinuousRecognitionAsync(), a keyword to stop voice recognition and begin processing. My question is, is it possible to just speak into the mic and then send the voice data off to be analysed, as close to natural conversation as possible? Or, is it possible to activate voice recognition for a set amount of time, stop recording after ten seconds, receive a response, and start listening again?
await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); speechRecognizer.Recognized += (s, e) => 
{ 
var result = e.Result; Debug.Log(result); 
} 
single shot version: var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
string newMessage = string.Empty; 
if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
 { 
Debug.Log(result.Text); 
}

Right now I have a working version that waits for a keyword and sends the data off, and a version that sends the voice data off on a button click. What I'm wondering is if it's even possible to just speak into the mic and receive a TTS response, as close as possible to a real conversation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@vvv please share the code you tried in the above question in text format.

always on version:
await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
speechRecognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
{
var result = e.Result;
Debug.Log(result);
}
single shot version:
var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
string newMessage = string.Empty;
if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
{
Debug.Log(result.Text);
}

Yes, it is possible to create a more natural conversational experience with Azure Cognitive Services, where the system continuously listens for speech input and processes it.
The below code for continuous speech recognition and synthesis using  Cognitive Service.
    var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);

    using var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig);
    StringBuilder recognizedTextBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    // Subscribe to events
    recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Recognizing: {e.Result.Text}");
    };

    recognizer.Recognized += async (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
        {
            recognizedTextBuffer.Append(e.Result.Text + " ");

            // Example action: Check for a specific keyword
            if (e.Result.Text.ToLower().Contains("stop"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Stopping recognition...");
                await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                // Synthesize the recognized text
                await SynthesizeSpeechAsync(e.Result.Text);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No speech could be recognized.");
        }
    };

    recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Session stopped.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    };

    // Start continuous recognition
    await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Say something... Say 'stop' to end the recognition.");
    Console.ReadKey();

    // Optionally stop recognition when exiting the application
    await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
}

static async Task SynthesizeSpeechAsync(string text)
{
    var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);
    speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-AvaMultilingualNeural";

    using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

    var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);

    switch (result.Reason)
    {
        case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
            Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for text: [{text}]");
            break;
        case ResultReason.Canceled:
            var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
 ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/NHkjzTI.png)           Console.WriteLine($"Synthesis canceled: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

            if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
            }
            break;
    }
}

Output:


Yes, that's what I assumed. But this can't be done without keywords, can it? So something like "stop" or "ok google" is still needed to stop/start it. Is it possible to have a completely seamless conversation the way two people talk- basically, it stops listening after the user has finished speaking?

I above code stops when telling stop

@vvv using   isRecognizing = false; stops listening after the user has finished speaking

well, I don't think it solved the problem, because this uses "stop" as a trigger, and doesn't stop naturally when the user has finished talking. does isRecognizing = false work automatically or would you have to set this boolean somewhere?

set this boolean

By using a boolean flag (isRecognizing), you can control when the application stops listening for user input, effectively creating conversational interaction where the system listens until the user indicates they have finished speaking. Adjust the keyword ("stop" in this case) as needed to fit your triggers.
